# A Current-limiting Design

Tags: transistors, circuit-design, circuit-protection

I want to design a circuit that monitors the flow of the current. If it reaches above the threshold of 600mA or so, it would open circuit. Where should I start? Is there any available designs I can reference? If not, how I can design one with transistors?

Edit:

I want thank everyone for answering the question. I apologize that I didn't give enough information(tbh I didn't have enough info). This "current monitor" will be used to protect some diodes. The supply is DC, and the current will be no more than 2A max. Instead of opening the circuit after reaching 600mA, is there a way to drive the excessive current to a load resistor or something? Preferably minimum voltage to be around 3V.

Comment: Maybe a curren sensor with a microcontroller and a Mosfet output, o maybe a Relay output

Comment: This is called an electronic fuse. Or just a regular fuse, if you're okay with the slow response.

Comment: `Where should I start?` At the beginning: Document how it is to work. You presented a start: *open circuit after ever reaching a threshold*. Add what is to happen while threshold not reached.

Comment: What happens after the circuit opens -- current goes below threshold, it instantly turns back on, etc.?  Should it wait some time after turning off? Before turn-off (some inrush allowed)? Latch off until manual reset? And in the mean time (before it responds), should current be limited in any particular way?

Comment: Also look up "current foldback" as a concept and see if this could also be of service to you.

Comment: It is called " circuit breaker".

Comment: You haven't told us anything useful except "600mA". There are a dozen ways to approach this, each one appropriate for a certain use case. To answer you, we need a lot more information about your own case. AC? DC? Input voltage? Minimum acceptable output voltage? That's where you start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q4 is a load switch.
Q1 and Q2 is a latching circuit (memory).
Q3 measure the shunt voltage, so the current.

Initially to switch the load on you must press a reset button, so it turns on the latch (both Q1 and Q2 on) and Q4 also.
After load current reaches about 600mA (0.3V shunt voltage) the Q3 turns the latch off (both Q1 and Q3 off) what closes a Q4.
To switch the load on again you must press a reset button.

The "turn off" current is given by:
**Vbe_Q3 - Vf_D1 = 0.6 - 0.3 = 0.3V**
**0.3V / 0.47ohm = 600mA**
, so you can control it by changing a shunt resistance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faRuqK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, great design! Is D1 a zener diode for constant voltage drop? Also, how difficult would it be if I want to limit the current to 600mA and drive excessive to a load? That would be modifying the Q3 transistor I assume?

Comment: D1 is schottky. It holds the Q3 closed when shunt voltage drop is below 0.3V (no overcurrent state). At 0.4V shunt drop + 0.3V on D1 = 0.7V the Q3 starts to conduct and turns off the latch (i.e. disconnects the load).

Comment: The schematic is set to protect load when current rises above 600mA as I mention in answer. By changing the shunt value you can change this overcurrent level.